# Swiping through a stack of images?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I recently came across this app, tinder, which has a really cool functionality.

You start off with X images. User can swipe left or right to go through each image to signal whether the user likes or dislikes something.

An image can be seen here: [image]

I have been looking at UICollectionView to do this, but I am a little confused about the custom layout I should be using.

I have been thinking of generating a bunch of cells and then setting different z-index and stacking them on top of one another with the same frame.x.

Any tutorial/advise/help available?

Answer (score 2):

This is simple UIImageviews. and tinder only showing two top images and set a background frame just like facebook image gallery.

When you swipe top image current thread fire next image and it replace current image with new image. And you can add like, comment views as you want.

Answer (score 2):

This sounded like fun, so I built an open-source library that mimics the interface you described.

https://github.com/modocache/MDCSwipeToChoose

The sample app included in the project is nearly identical to the UI in your screenshot.

Comment: Modocache, your code looks great. Any chance you'll be trying out this project with a different stack? I'm trying to figure out something similar with jQuery and wish I had some example code to look at.

Comment: No plans to do so at the moment, sorry!

Comment: @modocache never mine:) I found it :) Many thanks anyway